# How remove duplicates from relationship column when using pagination - laravel7?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

in  customer shop i have a category table  with separate table for translations. For example purpose i've cutted tables to only few columns:

**categories table:**

```
+---+-------------------+
|id | active            |
+---+-------------------+
| 1 | 1                 |
| 2 | 0                 | 
| 3 | 1                 | 
| 4 | 1                 | 
+---+-------------------+
```

**category_langs table containing translations**

```
+------------+---------+----------+
|id_category | id_lang | name     |
+------------+--------------------+
| 1          | 1       | Indigo   |
| 2          | 1       | Aramis   |
| 3          | 1       | Aramis   |
| 4          | 1       | Alto     |
+------------+--------------------+
```

In category_langs table there  is  **duplicate** entry on column **name**. Question is how to get all categories without duplicates using laravel pagination?

Example result should be(names not duplicated):

```
1 - Indigo
2 - Aramis 
4 - Alto
```

My code for getting categories:

```
$categories = Category::with('translation', 'images')->active()->paginate($perPage)->onEachSide(1);
```

I have solution with join but it's not keeping relations. Relatations must be kept.

```
$categories = Category::leftJoin('category_langs', 
           'category_langs.id_category', '=', 'categories.id')
           ->select('*')
           ->groupBy('category_langs.name')
           ->with('translation', 'images')->active()->paginate($perPage)->onEachSide(1);
```

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I Think this is what you need:

```
$categories =  Category::with(['translation'=>function($query) {
$query->distinct();} , 'images'] )->active()->paginate($perPage)->onEachSide(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for help but query result is the same as i was before. I've tried also ->distinct('name') and it caused disappearing translation  but category was still loaded.